# Java - Generic Types - Type Erasure

Tags: java, generics

I found the following question and answer on the oracle website

**What is the following class converted to after type erasure?**

```
public class Pair<K, V> {

    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey(); { return key; }
    public V getValue(); { return value; }

    public void setKey(K key)     { this.key = key; }
    public void setValue(V value) { this.value = value; }

    private K key;
    private V value;
}
```

**Answer:**

```
public class Pair {

    public Pair(Object key, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Object getKey()   { return key; }
    public Object getValue() { return value; }

    public void setKey(Object key)     { this.key = key; }
    public void setValue(Object value) { this.value = value; }

    private Object key;
    private Object value;
}
```

But when i decompile the class file using JD-GUI, i still see all the generic types similar what i have in the actual source code.

Does this mean that the generic types are retained in the class file? i'm using Java 6.

The decompiler version of the class using JD-GUI is as follows. I'm using Eclipse Helios to compile the class.

```
public class Pair<K, V>
{
  private K key;
  private V value;

  public Pair(K key, V value)
  {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }
  public K getKey() {
    return this.key; } 
  public V getValue() { return this.value; } 
  public void setKey(K key) {
    this.key = key; } 
  public void setValue(V value) { this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling the classes? Debugging information might be included with certain compiler options.

Comment: I'm using eclipse. So, it compiles the classes automatically. And then i'm using JD-GUI tool to decompile the class file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some generic type information is retained in the .class file - enough to allow you to determine, via reflection, that the type Pair is generic, and for classes that have Pair members, what the types of the generic parameters are and so on. The fact that this information is retained forms the basis of techniques like [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) that allow you pass around type tokens which retain information about their generic parameters.

Outside of reflection, however, type erasure means that the `Pair` class is mostly going to behave as in the stripped version in the "Answer" from the Oracle website.  In particular, the actual bytecode for the methods won't have reference to generic types `K` or `V` - only Object, and the method signatures will accept and return `Object`.

In this case, JD-GUI is just being smart and using the information stored in the .class file to restore the generic information in the decompiled output, but rest assure the types are erased in the bytecode.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I've read about reflection having acccess to generic type. And i read that the class signature contains the generic type information. One thing i don't understand is this "**the actual bytecode for the methods won't have reference to generic types K or V - only Object**". So, is the decompiled version of the class is wrong, which is exactly similar to the source code? In JD-GUI it shows as follows: 
public class Pair<K, V>
{
  private K key;
  private V value; ................

Comment: Maybe it would help if you posted the decompiled version of the classes.

What I mean is that the bytecode will be manipulating `Objects` not K or V (which aren't concrete types anyway). It could be that your dissassembler is being nice and using the generic information recorded in the class file to display the generic types, but the bytecodes themselves won't reflect that (for example, a cast to `(V)` won't appear in the bytecode at all).

Comment: Alternate phrasing: the bytecode knows there is a variable named `K`, but at runtime, if you have a `Pair<String, Integer>`, `K` won't be `String` -- it'll just be `Object`.

Comment: Well the variable is named (for example) `key` here, not `K`.  Do you mean that the bytecode knows that there is a type named `K`?

Comment: "**In this case, JD-GUI is just being smart and using the information stored in the .class file**" This answers my question...Thanks so much.

Comment: "What I mean is that the bytecode will be manipulating Objects not K or V (which aren't concrete types anyway)." Well, the actual bytecode doesn't have "types" for variables. You won't be "manipulating an Object" or "manipulating a String" or "manipulating a K"; you will just be manipulating a reference value. "Types" apply to variables, which are a compile-time concept. At runtime, you just have values.

Comment: Well types are both a compile-time and runtime concept, but I agree with you that there are *fewer* types at runtime - much of the type information disapears as verification has already proven that certain objects satisfy some type bounds.  Some type-aware things like instanceof and casts do extend to the bytecode however, so there can be a concrete differences in the emitted bytecode for a method that is generic versus the non-generic equivalent where some type parameter is replaced with a concrete type.

Comment: For example, an unchecked cast to type parameter `(T)` is not visible in the bytecode, while a cast to a non-generic type `(Foo)` is.

Comment: @BeeOnRope - Btw, there is a follow up to your answer over here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058227/java-type-erasure-why-can-i-see-the-type-when-i-look-at-the-bytecode

Comment: @MasterJoe2 - thanks. I should clarify that when I say "byte code" I really mean in the _byte code_: i.e., the instructions in the .class file. In that answer OP and Peter are using it more loosely to mean "everything in the .class file". The metadata for the class retains the type of the methods, and `javap -d` will show this above the byte code, but the byte code itself in this case won't have a trace of the class. Even this explanation is incomplete though: in other cases, e.g., where a wildcard is used, the bound can be erased down to a specific class, ...

Comment: ... so if you have method taking an  `List<? extends String>`, then `String` methods may appear in the compiled bytecode of the class.

Comment: I think my answer is still fine for the example here: a Pair<K,V> class with unbound `K`, `V` - nothing about those types will show up in the implementation of the `Pair` class, as they aren't even types at all but unbound placeholders.